# symfony login event

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I try to create an event for when the user enters the system logged,

I have this code :

```
services:
    login_listener:
        class: mio\mioBundle\LoginListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onSecurityInteractiveLogin }
```

```php
<?php

namespace mio\mioBundle;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Event;

class LoginListener
{

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {

    }
}
?>
```

but in profiler no called listener what?

Comment: I need to create an event logged in to insert into the database when each date user connection. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a service implementing [`AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.html) and set it as a success handler in your firewall — search for `success_handler` on the [Security Configuration Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/security.html) page. You can implement whatever logic you need in the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method.

Comment: `success_handler` is deprecated since Symfony 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

Your code was the proper way. The profiler shows that event was not called probably cause of redirection after the login. The profiler shows you the latest request - the one after redirect. If you'd check profiler info for the last POST request (to login_check) you'd find that the event actually was called.

Working example: http://www.metod.si/login-event-listener-in-symfony2/